# Trigger a jQuery 3 Event with ctrlKey set

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-events, definitelytyped

I'm about to update to jQuery 3 on Typescript with current [Typedefinitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts).

When compiling code like

```
const event:JQuery.Event<HTMLElement, null> = $.Event("keydown");
event.which = 77;
event.ctrlKey = true;
$(window).trigger(event);
```

I get the following error

> TS2540: Cannot assign to 'ctrlKey' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

How can I fix this? This was no problem with jQuery 2 and wherever I look it's the recommended way to trigger an event with a set ctrlKey.

The only way to get around this compiler error is to rewrite it to

```
event["ctrl" + "Key"] = true;
```

but that feels way too hacky :) I'm looking for a smooth solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The following now works as of `@types/jquery@3.3.13` (fixed by [DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#29520](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29520)).

```js
const ev: JQuery.Event<Window> = $.Event("keydown");
ev.which = 77;
ev.ctrlKey = true;
$(window).trigger(ev);
```

---

For older versions, you would've had to use the following.

```js
const ev: JQuery.Event<Window> = $.Event("keydown", { ctrlKey: true });
ev.which = 77;
$(window).trigger(ev);
```